# Android login activity only shows Google sign-in upon launch

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

The first time opening a newly installed version of my app shows a custom login/register field and a Google sign-in button beneath the custom option. After logging in, I am brought to the MainActivity without an issue, however, when I try to re-launch the app, it always prompts me with the Google sign-in that I cannot get past without either logging in with a Google account or uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnClickListener {


private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    // Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

// UI references.
private EditText mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;

private Button mEmailSignInButton;
private Button mEmailRegisterButton;
private SignInButton googleSignInButton;

// Firebase Auth
private FirebaseAuth fbAuth;
private FirebaseUser fbu;

// Firebase DB
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myUsers;

// Google
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edittext);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edittext);

    googleSignInButton= (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button);
    googleSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptEmailLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    mEmailRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    mEmailRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptEmailRegister();
        }
    });

    mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptEmailLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

    // Google sign in
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    // Initialize FirebaseAuth instance
    fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fbu = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (fbu != null) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth
                .GoogleSignInApi
                .getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No user is logged in");
    }

    // FireBase DB
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myUsers = database.getReference("users");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fbu = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (fbu != null) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth
                .GoogleSignInApi
                .getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No user is logged in");
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity (AppCompatActivity) */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private void attemptEmailRegister() {

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt register and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // perform the user register attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        fbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Register success
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            onAuthSuccess(user);
                        } else {
                            // If register fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Registration authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(startMainActivity);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


}

private void attemptEmailLogin(){

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt register and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // perform the user register attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(startMainActivity);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(startMainActivity);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }


}

private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
    String username = usernameFromEmail(user.getEmail());
    String[] names = firstAndLastNameFromDisplayName(user.getDisplayName());

    // Write new user
    writeNewUser(user.getUid(), names, username, user.getEmail());

    // Go to MainActivity
    Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startMainActivity);
    finish();
}
private String usernameFromEmail(String email) {
    if (email.contains("@")) {
        return email.split("@")[0];
    } else {
        return email;
    }
}
private String[] firstAndLastNameFromDisplayName(String fullName) {
    if (fullName != null) {
        if (fullName.contains(" ")) {
            return new String[]{fullName.split(" ")[0], fullName.split(" ")[1]};
        } else {
            return new String[]{fullName, "emptyLastName"};
        }
    } else {
        return new String[]{"defaultfirst","defaultlast"};
    }
}
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String[] names, String username, String email) {
    User user = new User(username,names[0],names[1], email);
    myUsers.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    return (password.length() > 4) && !password.contains("\\");
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed called");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.google_sign_in_button:
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        Log.d(TAG, "google handleSignInResult: success!");
        Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(startMainActivity);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "HandleSignInResult malfunction. Try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(startMainActivity);
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    fbAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(startMainActivity);
                    }

                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: What is the launcher activity? Is it Log in Activity or Main Activity?

Comment: @SrikarReddy LoginActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite a simple fix. I was misled by the boilerplate Firebase structure, when the logic doesn't exactly apply to my instance:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

But LoginActivity.java only really needs to prompt when the button is pressed, not `onCreate()` or `onStart()`. **Here's the fix**:

```
// Initialize FirebaseAuth instance
        fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fbu = fbAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (fbu == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No user is logged in");
//            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
//            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "User is already logged in");
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate` and `onStart` you've `fbAuth.getCurrentUser()`. It is null when the user hasn't logged in otherwise it returns user details.

Your logic is in reverse asking for a sign in if the user has already logged in.

```
if (fbu != null) {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth
            .GoogleSignInApi
            .getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    finish();
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No user is logged in");
}
```

This should be in reverse

```
if (fbu == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "No user is logged in");
    // Initiate Google sign in
    Intent signInIntent = Auth
            .GoogleSignInApi
            .getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "User is already logged in");
    // Open Main Activity
    Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startMainActivity);
    // Close the current activity
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Helps but doesn't fix the original issue. After logging in for the first time after the app has been downloaded, the app opens every time afterwards to the Google sign-in.

Comment: Can you try the edited code in both onCreate and onStart?

Comment: Yes, these give rise to the same issue. Because they are called upon launch of the app, the user doesn't have a chance to decide between custom auth or Google sign-in.